# convert string to date and store in sqlite in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have date like this in string datatype from server `2012-09-25 12:44:50.000`. How can i change into date and store in sqlite in android....

I have tried like this...

```
String ackwardDate="2012-09-25 12:44:50.000";
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
String ackwardRipOff = ackwardDate.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", "");
Long timeInMillis = Long.valueOf(ackwardRipOff);
calendar.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis);
values.put(DBCREATIONDATE,calendar.getTime().toGMTString());
```

but i am getting Invalid Long : `"2012-10-30T03:12:53.827"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

Date date1 =  sdf.parse("2012-09-25 12:44:50.000");

long millisec = date1.getTime();

System.out.println(""+millisec);
```

Comment: getting Invalid Long : "2012-10-30T03:12:53.827"

Answer (score 0):

What type of data type you define in your sqlite database for store datetime?. If it is Text type then you need to convert this data value to string.

SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as `TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER` values:

```
`TEXT` as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
`REAL` as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
`INTEGER` as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
```

Applications can chose to store dates and times in any of these formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in date and time functions.

Comment: sqlite in date datatype